Regex statement works in Regex101 but not working in python
I have need of a regex that captures text between a key word and the next instance of a date. It should capture the keyword and date as well.
The expression I am currently using is as follows:
r"Chapter.+?(?:(Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?|Apr(il)?|May|June?|July?|Aug(ust)?|Sep(t(ember)?)?|Oct(ober)?|Nov(ember)?|Dec(ember)?)[ ](3[01]|[12][0-9]|[0][1-9]|[1-9])[,][ ](20\d{2}))"

I am using the expression as follows, where regex is my expression above:
updates = re.findall(regex, text)

When I use Regex101 or regexr this seems to be correct, but when using in Python I get unexpected results. For example, if the source text was
"text text Chapter 5 text text text November, 12 2024. Text Text" 

the result is coming out looking something like this:
('November', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'ember', '', '12', '2024')

I would instead like to see the result be ('Chapter 5 text text text November, 12 2024"

If you want fewer captures, have fewer capturing groups. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall

Did you choose "Python" as regex flavor on regex101.com?

Thank you - I didn't realize that is how capturing groups worked. I've got it working as needed now.

Just write a simple regex and then code the rest: see here.

TLDR: use non-capturing groups, or just iterate over the results of re.finditer.
